# Can't make twitter status post as it is seen on twitter, I get two question marks

Tags: php, unicode, twitter, render

I am trying to render a twitter post that contains unicode (generated aparently with iphone)
This is the direct api call to the status:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=199169641627660288&include_entities=0
It contains a 11:11 and a smiley.

I cant make it render properly in PHP, what am I missing? I get two question marks.

Comment: Have you tried adding `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: How exactly are you outputting this status?

Comment: The problem was with the way I was decoding the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Write this in your file at the top.

Comment: This is the correct answer for my question, although my problem was in the origin: the json::decode function I was using was decoding the json wrong... but with json_decode worked OK. Unfortunatelly json_decode does not work ok in several other samples...